# Where is Serial.begin() Serial.println("hi") supposed to output to?

Tags: arduino, teensy

I have a teensy in midi mode, and I thought Serial.begin(9600) and Serial.println("hello world") ; would show something in the console. It doesn't show anything. 
Where is Serial.println() supposed to output to? 
I would like to see feedback from my potentiometer.

Answer (score 2):

It outputs to the device which you are connected to via Serial. For example, if you are connected to your PC, you can access it with the Serial monitor embedded in Arduino IDE, or other applications such as Putty by choosing the right port COM number and baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

Found it , it is under Arduino -> Tools -> Serial Monitor.